# Audio player for transcribing and taking notes of meeting recordings

Tags: audio, mediaplayer

I am looking for a macOS audioplayer that helps me to relisten to my recorded meetings and at the same time make notes.

The player should

- support global hotkeys (without requiring the app to be in the foreground) for rewinding a few seconds, pause, and play
- and also allow adjusting the playing speed (e.g., 1.5x).

I have tried several solutions yet: VLC, iTunes, QuickTime. But none of these fulfilled all of my requirements.

Currently, I am using [otranscribe.com](https://otranscribe.com/) which is tedious to use as it only supports some very basic formatting (e.g., not bullet points) in the text section. Because of that I am using GoogleDocs to write my notes which requires skipping back and forth between tabs.

Do you have any suggestions? A free solution would be nice but I am also open for paid/commercial solutions.

Comment: All the (quality) transcription software I’ve ever seen has been on a Windows.  It’s just the industry.

Comment: @Allan It must not be a transcription software at all. I do not need the adv. features (e.g., pedal support, timestamps) they provide—a good audio player with the mentioned capabilities would be enough. Any suggestions what I could try?

Comment: I don't know of any that meet your requirements.  *Audio* players are geared toward audio listening and for the most part managing a music library.  An audio player geared toward transcribing, whether it has "advanced features" or not is a completely different animal.

Comment: Maybe a podcast player, but all the ones I've seen and tried only allow 15/30/60 second jumps.  I know you can speed up playback, but I definately know there isn't any "global shortcuts.  Try [Overcast.fm](https://overcast.fm/)

Comment: @Allan Great, thanks! I will give it a try. I found out that using BetterTouchTools one can forward shortcuts to apps, i.e., define global shortcuts that trigger certain shortcuts in an app. Maybe I can combine that with VLC or another player. // EDIT: Oh, Overcast.fm it is not an macOS app. Unfortunately, I do not have an iPhone but PodcastAddicted for Android could be an alternative.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I finally ended up using VLC player which provides (non-global) shortcuts for the required functions (e.g., <kbd>␣</kbd> for play/pause, <kbd>⌘</kbd>+<kbd>⌃</kbd>+<kbd>←</kbd> for a very short backward skip).

I then used [BetterTouchTools](https://folivora.ai/) to allow invoking these shortcuts globally by adding new keyboard shortcuts that use the action *send shortcut to specific app* to forward the custom-defined global shortcuts to VLC.